# image upload jquery without form

Tags: jquery

I have a html like this.

```
<div id="cb">
    <span>
       <br>
       "test.jpg"
    </span>
    <br>
    <img src="datat:image/jpeg;base64/9ikdsaasdflaljkf" class ="0">
</div>
```

I am trying to upload the file on button click without form submit. I am following a tutorial which says

```
var file = $("#cb")[0].files[0];
```

But this line I am not getting any value. Can anybody help me.

Comment: var file = $("#cb")[0].files[0].name; on button click

Comment: yes, that is not possible?

Comment: what you want to get?

Comment: i am trying to upload file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload').on('click', function() {
        var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

        $.ajax({
                url         : 'upload.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache       : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                data        : form_data,                         
                type        : 'post',
                success     : function(output){
                    alert(output);              // display response from the PHP script, if any
                }
         });
         $('#pic').val('');                     /* Clear the file container */
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="pic" type="file" name="pic" />
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
</body>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    if ( $_FILES['file']['error'] > 0 ){
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
        {
            echo "File Uploaded Successfully";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yes I am following like this : but in my case  for  var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0]; I didnot get any value

Answer (score 2):

Your code like this

```js
  $('#btn-upload').click(function() {
   var file = $("#cb")[0].files[0].name;
   console.log(file);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
   <td><div id="cp"></div></td>
   <td>
       <input id="cb" type='file' name="cb" />
       <button type="submit" name="btn-upload" id="btn-upload">upload</button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Glad it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

The file control doesnot have file initially so it is showing empty.
You can fetch after clicking on upload so fetch file inside upload button click event after you have browsed for file

```
$('#btn-upload').click(function(){

 var file = $("#cb")[0].files[0];
 alert(file); // Shows [object File] i.e. file object

 var fileName = $("#cb")[0].files[0].name; // Gives filename

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudinary's jQuery file upload plugin, with this solution you can upload images directly from the browser.

Download jquery.cloudinary.js from the js folder of the GitHub project and in your HTML pages, include jquery.cloudinary.js after including the jQuery library.

```
<script src='jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery.cloudinary.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

download the following files from the js folder of the GitHub project as well.

```
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.iframe-transport.js
jquery.fileupload.js
```

and Include all required jQuery files in your HTML page:

```
<script src='jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery.ui.widget.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery.iframe-transport.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery.fileupload.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jquery.cloudinary.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

You can find more information here. http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration